# session variables in django

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

In my django project I have the following portion of HTML:

```
 <div class="box">

               <form class="form" action="/create_cv" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row uniform 50%">
                    <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                        {{form.numtel}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row uniform">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <ul class="actions align-center">
                            <li><input type="submit" value="OK"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


                </div>
```

I want to get the value of form.numtel in order to use it in my python function,

```
def getFormation(request):
    user = request.user
    if user and user.is_active:
        u= " HEREEEE I WANT TO USE IT ""
        ....
```

So I tried to use `request.session` but it returns an error which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the session here? Why not just get it from the form data?

Comment: `request.POST["numtel"]`?